# Visual Studio publishing files with older dates (not up to date)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, publishing

I encounter a strange behaviour with an ASP.NET project's deployment.

When I publish it, it does copy files into the publish directory.
But it publishes OLD versions of some of the files (files date is 1 week ago)!
The same happens if I delete the concerned files before hitting the publish button.
I am using the "files system" publish mode.
As a matter of fact, when I start the project in release mode, the old code is being used.

Even stranger, I have noticed that if I run this sequence:

- clean solution
- regenerate solution
- publish the web project (part of this solution) causing the old version problem --> so files are being deployed with wrond dates as explined
- clear web cache to be sure
- start the project in release mode

Then the old code is being executed as described.

Now If I do this way:

- clean solution
- regenerate solution
- publish the web project (part of this solution) causing the old version problem --> so files are being deployed with wrond dates as explined
- clear web cache to be sure
- start the project in release mode : old code is being executed
- stop the execution

**-  start the project in debug mode** 
       -> the up to date files are being used as it does not use the deploy 
folder at all

- stop debug execution
- start the project in release mode again:
  then the new code is being executed!!!

As if having run the project in debug mode forced the files to use the up to date version.
And even even stranger, at this stage, although VS seems to use the correct versions, the files dates is still wrong which lets me suspect that the concerned files are still not up to date....

I am completely puzzled!!